# Describe OpenAPI schema for TypeScript Interface {[key: string]: string[]}

Tags: typescript, openapi, jsonschema

How do I describe an OpenAPI 3.x.x schema for this TypeScript interface?

```
interface Test {
  [key: string]: string[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with additionalProperties.  It means any property defined will be an array of strings

OpenAPI is based on JSON Schema and they say:

> In JSON, the "keys" must always be strings.

```yaml
title: Test
type: object
additionalProperties:
  type: array
  items:
    type: string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JSON Schema which is part of OpenAPI:

```
{
  "title": "Test",
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    ".*": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
         "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, it depends on your tooling on how it supports `patternProperties` or not.

Comment: This only works with OAS 3.1.0.  `patternProperties` is not allowed in OAS 3.0.x